# SharePoint framework - jquery loading issues

Tags: sharepoint-framework

I have a question about loading jquery as external in SharePoint Framework. I have worked through at least 20 different samples from at least as many different people and many of them MVP's. I can safely say that none of the samples is worth it's salt when it comes to explaining the concept to a beginner.

To load jquery as an external, what i have gathered is:
specify jquery as external as follows in the config.js file

```
          "externals": { 
              "jquery" : "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"

                      }
```

Once this is done, in the webpart.ts file,

```
                     import 'jquery';
                  declare var jQuery;
```

This doesn't seem to work at all. I have followed at least 20 different tutorials and samples. I can get it to work, however, if i did npm install jquery. Then it all works. However, none of the tutorials I have followed tell this step so I am not including that step either.

Can someone guide me the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: what error you are getting? Is it `error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jquery'.`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

Instead of

```
import 'jquery';
```

For reference [Loading a script from a CDN](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/basics/add-an-external-library#loading-a-script-from-a-cdn)